# Prefix or adjective meaning "one and a half"

Tags: meaning, adjectives, prefixes

Is there a prefix or adjective that means "one and a half", as "tri-" or "triple" is for "three"?

The exact usage I have is to describe "18" in terms of a dozen. Where I live they've started making 18-egg cartons, and the local grocer was wondering what name to give them in his computerised cash register, hoping for a single word.

Even slang, informal or invented term would do if there isn't such a term already.

Comment: I've wondered about this myself; in Russian there's [полтора](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) which is a very useful and common term. Your grocer should spearhead the initiative to create a new word :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Sesqui-*.

However, it certainly isn't informal, and is also pretty obscure. About the only use of it is *sesquicentennial* and *sesquipedalian* which is at a few removes (it literally means 18inches long but it's originally figurative meaning of using long words is the only English meaning).

It certainly wouldn't go with *dozen*; one would just say "one and a half dozen", "dozen and a half" or "eighteen".

Edit:

If you really want a word meaning 18 of something, you've got *octodecuple*, which has been used in mathematics at least as far back as 1816 and probably earlier. But really, don't; unless you're talking about properties of mathematical tuples where octodecuples are interesting in some particular way, it would just be horrible.

Comment: It is definitely obscure.  If I asked at the market for a sesquidozen eggs, I'd more likely expect to receive a puzzled look than 18 eggs!

Comment: @Ste and anyone who did get *sesqui-* might object to it being used with *dozen*.

Comment: Absolutely. So we can conclude that it should be avoided at all costs, else we truly have egg on our faces.

Comment: @Ste, there are running jokes in some nerdy/techie circles of deliberately coining such outrages, with e.g. *microfortnight* and *nanocentury* being used in some computing contexts due to such humour; but the humour is there precisely because they're clearly such bad ideas.

Comment: Oh, I'm definitely going to use those two!

Comment: @Ste OpenVMS actually used microfortnights, and I it can be found as an available unit some other places.

Comment: @ste it *is* for eggs! See edit to question

Comment: the word 'dozen' derives from Latin as well but through old French. Hence if a neologism is invited 'sesqui-duodenary' as suggested would be better as both components of the word are directly derived from Latin

Comment: Yeah, *sesquiduodenary* at least makes more sense and is slightly more graceful than *sesquidozen*, but it's no more graceful than *octodecuple* which also already exists as a word.

Comment: Bookmark this question - "Sesquidozen" will be the word of choice in three years!  And it all started here and in Bohemian's town!

Comment: @Ste how depressing!

Answer (score 7):

One does occasionally hear the term ***[three-halves](http://www.wordiq.com/definition/Three_halves)***.

An on-line search for *three-halves* yields many results, including

- this image <sup>[3](http://www.learnnc.org/lp/multimedia/7705)</sup>
  [image]
- many references to *Games of Three-halves*, including Three-sided football <sup>[4](http://www.nextleft.org/2010/04/game-of-three-halves.html)</sup>, three types of 'football' played in Northern Ireland <sup>[5](http://www.irishfa.com/news/item/6585/game-of-three-halves/)</sup>
- a theatre performance <sup>[6](http://pelicantheatre.org.au/html/three_halves.html)</sup>
- three-halves as a *Superparticular number* <sup>[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_halves)</sup>
- and numerous other varied references.

The expression ***three-ha'-pence*** was in common usage in the UK until 1971 as a common way of expressing 1½d (one-and-a-half pence) in the pre-decimal currency system (1½d  = 1/160th of a pound sterling £).

An English three-halfpence silver coin was minted around 1561-1582 during the reign of Elizabeth I. <sup>[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_halfpence_%28English_coin%29)</sup>

British three-halfpence silver coins were produced for use in certain British colonies at various times during the reign of Queen Victoria (1819 - 1901)<sup>[9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_halfpence_%28British_coin%29)</sup>, as illustrated <sup>[11](http://www.coins-of-the-uk.co.uk/pics/phalf.html)</sup>:
[image]

<sub>P.S. In answer to the original question, I would not suggest using the expression *three half-dozens* unless you want to test your readers / listeners!</sub>

Comment: Pictures always make an answer better :)

Answer (score 4):

The prefix that means "times one and a half" is *sesqui-*, as in *sesquicentennial* for the 150<sup>th</sup> anniversary of something.

The OED includes the following terms that begin with *sesqui-*:

> sesquialter, sesquialtera, sesquialteral, sesquialterate, sesquialterous, sesquibasic,
>   sesquicentenary, sesquicentennial, sesquicompound, sesquiduple,
>   sesquiduplicate, sesquinonal, sesquiocellus, sesquioctaval, sesquioxidation,
>   sesquioxide, sesquioxidic, sesquioxidized, sesquipedal, sesquipedalian,
>   sesquipedalianism, sesquipedality, sesquiplane, sesquiplicate, sesquiquadrate,
>   sesquiquarta, sesquiquartal, sesquiquintile, sesquiseptimal, sesqui-square,
>   sesquiterpene, sesquitertia, sesquitertial, sesquitertian, sesquitertious.

So it is hardly informal or slang; anything but, actually: it's rather a bit fancy.

Comment: I'd still say that *sesquicentenary* (and *-ennial*) and *sesquipedalian* would be the only that would see much use, and off those the last's etymological connection to "one and a half" isn't vital to understanding it.

Comment: @JonHanna Those are the only ones I'm apt to use myself, that's for sure. Hm, given that the word *duodecuple* exists, I suppose one could justly derive *sesquiduodecuple* from it. But it won't win you friends in low places, that's for sure. There's probably some sort of *octodecuple* that would work better.

Comment: Especially since if you were really going to use *sesquiduodecuple* you could use the already-attested *octodecuple*. My answer hence updated to include that you could, and of course that you shouldn't!

Comment: Ah, I see you edited that comment to consider octodecuple too, as I was replying.

Comment: In mathematics we have *sesquilinear*, which, roughly speaking, is something linear in one variable and semilinear in the other..

Answer (score 3):

Another, rather archaic ordinal description is "half *again* as." That has the connotation of "half more" over one.

Comment: I like that this is a native English answer. “Dozen and half again (as many)” is more natural, but “half again a dozen” is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

***sesqui-duodenary***

This is my suggested neologism.

Both component words directly originate from their Latin counterparts:

[sesqui-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sesqui?s=t) and  [duodenary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/duodenary?s=t)

Answer (score 0):

Hendecasyllabic is derived from Greek for an 11 syllable word litterally meaning 11 sounds. The greek prefix for 18 would be octodeca- I wouldn't know how to form a noun from it. But here is a great resource on [greek and latin numerical prefixes](http://phrontistery.info/numbers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Where I come from, 18 is called "chai" from the two Hebrew letters that make up the word. Giving in multiples of 18 is considered good fortune as it's symbolic of giving life. I doubt, though, that you could refer to a dozen and a half eggs as a chai of eggs in a grocery without some perplexed looks, unless of course there are customers familiar with the term.