# Centennial and a half? SemiBiCentennial?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Considering that "semicentennial" refers to 50 years and "centennial" refers to 100 years and "bicentennial" refers to 200 years, what similar word is appropriate for 150 years?

Comment: A little more research and I've found the answer to my own question!

Comment: "Sesquicentennial" is the answer I was seeking.

Comment: Related: *[Prefix or adjective meaning “one and a half”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123147)*

Comment: @choster It's not just related; the top answer there answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

That would be *sesquicentennial*; the prefix [*sesqui*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sesqui) means one-and-a-half times.